# Form onsubmit which places an ajax call does not return before the form goes to its action. However works on mac but not PC

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I am building an application in Django that creates rubrics to grades assignments. Each rubric item is editable and on submission of the form, the page is checking if a rubric item has been edited and if it has editing it in the database. Then once all those have been updated, it will submit the checked checkboxes as the grade. So the form action is to submit the grade, and in the jquery I have an event listener checking for when the submit button is clicked that will make an ajax call to update the rubric entries. The rubric entries arent being edited before the form goes to its action. Like its going to the form action too quickly the jquery doesnt have time to finish.

I've tried doing event.preventDefault to prefent the form from going to the action and then submiting the form after the loop that edits all the rubric entries which should give it time to finish. I've also tried calling this function in an onsubmit instead of an onclick because I heard that the onsubmit executes before the form action does. But here's the thing. The code works perfectly on my mac, but does not work on 2 other PCs. Every fix I've tried still works on my mac but still doesn't work on the PCs.

When I change the form submit button to type 'button' which means the form never goes to its action, or after doing event.preventDefault never submit the form, the edit function works properly so I've concluded that the problem is that the form action is disrupting the other function but I just cant figure out why when I've taken measures to try to stop it, and why only on PC?

```
<form action="{% view to upload grade %}" method="post" id="upload_form"> 
    <ol id="form_list">...</ol>
    <button type="submit" id="submit_grade">Submit Grade</button>
</form>




$(document).on('click', "#submit_grade", function(event){
event.preventDefault();

  $(".rubricEntry").each(function(){
     var crit_pk = $(this).attr('id');
     var description = $(this).find(".rubricField-description").text();
     var points = parseInt($(this).find(".rubricField-points").text());

     console.log("points:" + points +"   description: " + description);

     if(description === textPlaceholder || isEmptyorSpaces(description) ){
        console.log("empty or description");
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '/upload/delete/'+ a_canvasId+'/' + crit_pk +'/',
           data:{ csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
           },
           dataType: 'html',
           success: function() {
           }
        });
     } 

     else{
        console.log("tried to edit");
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '/upload/edit/'+ a_canvasId+'/' + crit_pk + '/',
           data:{ csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
              point_value: points,
              description: description
           },
           dataType: 'html',
           success: function() {
              console.log("success");
           }
        });
     }
  });
  document.getElementById("upload_form").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding async: false, to the ajax call.